# Is it viable to use Strapi in my application?

Tags: strapi

I'm currently exploring the feasibility of incorporating Strapi into my existing application, which is deployed as microservices in a Kubernetes (k8s) environment. At the moment, we utilize ktor for our APIs, and the requests involve more than just simple SELECT queries, including retrieving data from other pods and performing calculations.

Additionally, our database consists of numerous tables and a substantial amount of data. Therefore, I'm uncertain about Strapi's capability to efficiently import both the relationships between tables and the data itself.

The primary reasons for considering the adoption of Strapi are scalability and the ease of backend accessibility for frontend developers.